# How to token Insert nth element of Iframe?

Tags: 7, views, wysiwyg, tokens

Module used: [Token Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert)

I have a content type with an iframe field which accepts multiple values.
In my wysiwyg body field, I did a token insert.
When I add this iframe field which has only one value with token insert, it works perfect.

What to do if I want to insert only the second/third value of the multi value iframe field? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Basically I want to have control on which video to insert from the multi value iframe field.

[image]

Name of the field is Microsoft Video. So I took the token first and added delta as suggested below. [node:field_microsoft_video:1] This is printing the value as plain text after giving the delta.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Specify the raw token string with delta value?

Comment: So, the name of the field is Microsoft Video.I tried inserting [node:field_microsoft_video:1] without any luck. It just prints that as a plain string if I give delta value.